# monitor startup program behaviors and files accessed

Tags: windows, vpn, boot, procmon

Everytime I start my windows and login, I will see a copy file dialog.
which copy files from

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
to 
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\

i searched the folder it is used to store vpn data for current user and all users
I do not have any VPN connections
and my computer is just after a fresh re-installation.
most programs I installed are drivers.

I wan't to figure out which program does that
I thought I could monitor processes through SysInternal's procmon.exe
however, I can't start it so fast before the copy process finished.

How to?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://superuser.com/a/404073/23133.

Comment: Create a new user and login and see if it still happens?

Comment: +techie007, I read the article, it seems works, i will try it later. thanks!