# How does one find out what application is making RegSvr32 calls?

Tags: windows-7, dll, regsvr32

An application (or something else) keeps on trying to load DLL files using RegSvr32 when I start my computer and I keep on getting two log windows saying:

`The module "C:\Users\H*******\AppData\Local\IPsoft\loader_u.dll" failed to load`

`The module "C:\Users\H*******\AppData\Local\Evition\New.dll" failed to load`

I checked and neither of these files exists.

How can I find out what is trying to load these non-existent DLLs?

**Edit:** I am not trying to make a general log of all startup services and processes I am just trying to find what process/service made the calls:

`regsvr32 "C:\Users\H*******\AppData\Local\IPsoft\loader_u.dll"`

`regsvr32 "C:\Users\H*******\AppData\Local\Evition\New.dll"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to monitor programs and services on Windows startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/930338/how-to-monitor-programs-and-services-on-windows-startup)

Comment: The solution to your problem can be something that is not specific to RegSvr32.  Check to see what tries to access your AppData\Local folder.  Sysinternals can help.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and i think i have resolved it somewhat. i ungraded to windows 10 and the still didn't fix it so i tried to find whatever was trying to run at startup using msconfig . let me just say i think it is cool that you have a startup section in the task manager on windows 10. I disabled the two programs labelled "microsoft (C) register server"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I still know there is no direct way to detect this, but I fixed the issue by going to registry (WINDOWS + R, regedit) searching for the files being called and deleting the keys which referred to them.