# Windows Startups taking around 5 minutes to activate

Tags: windows-8, boot

**The Problem**

After I boot my windows 8 machine I notice two problems. The first problem doesn't always occur but that's the fact that my desktop icons are blank. Sometimes almost none of them are but others its almost all. The second problem is the fact that it takes around 5 minutes for the startup programs to start loading, in fact, it's not just applications such as Discord or Avast but also key files which I need in order to do anything on my computer. Often if I click in the bottom left corner on the windows icon it gets stuck...

Other than that, so far I have tried booting my pc in safe mode and even did a system restore. I have done several pc scans with avast and eg sfc /scannow in the cmd.

Comment: The thing is though, if I wait like 3-5 minutes the pc all of a sudden starts opening all my startup applications and other stuff and it works normally...

Comment: Check out my answer https://superuser.com/a/930357/337631, in particular the reference to Process Monitor.